# Have been trying to translate this.. hoping it some info of a great grandfather

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

[image]

I have been trying to translate this text from an church record any help would be very helpful.

Comment: **To close voters:** See  https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic revisited last year https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/sind-fragen-%c3%bcber-die-entschl%c3%bcsselung-von-schriften-auch-handschriften-on-topic  - the community vote clearly was *on topic*

Comment: As a  prerequierement, user  Takkat wrote there: "Whenever we are faced with contemporary handwritings we will have to take extra care that they are of general interest." This posting fails to apply. And "There should be at least some general, historical, or scientific interest in such a question." And "The more a question appears to be helpful for, or interesting to future visitors the more likely it will stay."

Comment: @userunknown: that was 5 years ago when I believed we need such a general interest as a restriction - the votes on answers on the revisited issue  last year showed that people consider German written in Kurrent alone suffices. The general interest in this case certainly is the wording of such a register which should be similar in other places.

Comment: @Takkat Direkt nach einer Übersetzung zu fragen ist der Grund, weswegen ich diese Frage schließen würde. Das muss davon abhängig sein, ob das lesbar ist oder nicht. Die Frage wird erst meines Erachtens on-topic sein, wenn der OP nicht nach einer Übersetzung sonder nach einer Entschlüsselung fragt.

Comment: @c.p diskutieren kann man sowas ja, aber bitte auf Meta und nicht hier. Eine Übersetzung ist angesichts der Schwierigkeiten mit Handschrift und Kurrent eher eine Nebensache.

Answer (score 5):

Here an attempt to transcription.

> 25  Register der Getauften 1772   (57)
>
> 148 Joh. Valtin Conrad Würtz  + 29. März 1851 Wurde den 5ten Jan:
>   zu Obliegen(?): Geboh: und den 7ten Getauft, der Vatter ist Magnus
>   Würtz, die Mutter Ang(elika):. Zeugen Conrad Kiester, Valtin Kiester,
>   des Valtin Kiesters Sohn zu Dürmingen, Luisa Kiestern des Ga. (=genannten??)
>   Kiesters zu Dürmingen Tochter.

Translation of content:

> I.e. Johann(es?) Valtin  Conrad Würth was born on the 5th of January in 1772 in Oberlinxweiler. He was baptized two days later on the 7th. The names of the father, the mother and the witnesses follow, The name of the village is most probably Dürmingen, an old spelling of Dirmingen in Saarland. Johann died on March the 29th 1851

The village Dirmingen is not very far from Oberlinxweiler, just a few miles.
Oberlinxweiler is since 1973 a district ("Stadtteil") of 66606 St. Wendel.
Dirmingen is since 1974 a district of 66571 Eppelborn.

Comment: Dürmingen may be an old spelling for Dirmingen (Saarland) - would be nice to get the other town too :)

Comment: @Takkat Possible, but the dialectal name of this village is "Derminga". Another candidate could be Dürningen, today Durningen in Alsace.

Comment: I hope the OP will shed some light into this it they eventually come back. At least they should know the region where their ancestors lived. They may even know the town names.

Comment: Could "Valter" actually be "Valtin", i.e. a dialectal form of "Valentin"? The last letter doesn't really look like an "r".

Comment: @MarcSchütz It seems you're quite right! I didn't know od this form of Valentin, but it makes much more sense than Valter. Where  is (was?) this name form common?

Comment: @Beta I knew it only from Eastern Franconia, but a quick search indicates that it indeed used to be widespread, e.g. https://www.faltin-ahnenforschung.com/der-name/

Comment: The town name that i Have is Oberlinxweiler. birth-5 Jan 1772, Death - 29 Mar 1851. Parents Magnus Wurtz and Angelika Wurtz.

Comment: And Oberlinxweiler is very near the village Dirmingen. I have edited the anwer accordingly